# Showing table from db in php via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i have following html code which should pass data from my db.

Could u help me a bit, i'm gettin error 500 in console, in every refresh i got DataTables warning: table id=logsListing - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7. Could someone explain me where's the probleme here. I mention that i already read that error and i tried to fix in many ways, but unfortunatelly i didn't figure it out..

page logs.php

```
<?php 
include('inc/header.php');
include('inc/container.php');
?>
<title>YBOMedia stocksync</title>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>  

<div class="container contact"> 
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">  
        
        <!-- <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                    <button type="button" name="add" id="addRecord" class="btn btn-success">Add New Record</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <table style="width: 1200px; align-content: center;" id="logsListing" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>                   
                    <th>Product Name</th>                   
                    <th>BaseLinker ID</th>                  
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

my part from ajax.js

```
        var DataTable = $('#logsListing').DataTable({
        "lengthChange": false,
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'serverMethod': 'post',     
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"ajax_logs.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{action:'listLogs'},
            dataType:"json"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[0, 1, 2, 3],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],
        "pageLength": 10
    });
```

ajax_logs.php

```
    <?php
    include_once 'config/Database.php';
    include_once 'class/Logs.php';
    
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    
    $record = new Records($db);
    
    if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'listLogs') {
        $record->listLogs();
    }
```

and my class Logs.php

```
<?php
    class Logs {    
       
        private $logsTable = 'Logs';
        public $id;
        public $Action;
        public $Result;
        public $Sync;
        private $conn;
        
        public function __construct($db){
            $this->conn = $db;
        }       
        
        public function listLogs(){
            
            $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->logsTable." ";
            if(!empty($_POST["search"]["value"])){
                $sqlQuery .= 'where(id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
                $sqlQuery .= ' OR Action LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';          
                $sqlQuery .= ' OR Result LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';      
            }
            
            if(!empty($_POST["order"])){
                $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
            } else {
                $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY id ASC ';
            }
            
            if($_POST["length"] != -1){
                $sqlQuery .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
            }
            
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();  
            
            $stmtTotal = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->logsTable);
            $stmtTotal->execute();
            $allResult = $stmtTotal->get_result();
            $allRecords = $allResult->num_rows;
            
            $displayRecords = $result->num_rows;
            $records = array();     
            while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $record['errorlog'] == 0)               
                $rows = array();            
                $rows[] = $record['id'];
                $rows[] = ucfirst($record['Action']);
                $rows[] = $record['Result'];        
                $rows[] = $record['Sync'];  
                $records[] = $rows;
            }
            $output = array(
                "draw"  =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),         
                "iTotalRecords" =>  $displayRecords,
                "iTotalDisplayRecords"  =>  $allRecords,
                "data"  =>  $records
            );
            
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please don't post code on 3rd party sites but inside your question. Thanks

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: How is your `Records`-class (which you create an instance of) related to your `Logs`-class (which is the class you've posted and the one containing the method `listLogs()`)? Is `Records` extending `Logs`, or are you instantiating the wrong class?

Comment: Basically Logs not equal with Records, but Logs it's a copy from recordsListing. It's a different class, called from different script (ajax_logs.php) , just in ajax.js i have all data included (from both classes).  , also find a missed thing in Logs $record['errorlog'] == 0)  deleted, but still not workin' , i'm sure that it's smthing that i miss but i can't figure it out where's the missing thing

Comment: Well have you tried looking at the error logs to work out what caused the 500 error?

Comment: @ADyson [Tue Oct 25 11:45:50.556665 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1047059:tid 140527370499840] [client 18.198.29.236:0] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in class/Logs.php:35\nStack trace:\n#0 ajax_logs.php(11): Logs->listLogs()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /class/Logs.php on line 35', referer: logs.php

Comment: So that means `$this->conn` was null when you tried to call the prepare() function on it. You'll need to do some debugging to find out why that happened. I'd guess presumably the connection was never initialised properly.

Comment: @ADyson yas, that was. i made the wrong connection, solved. Thx guyz for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql connection wasn't proper initiated.